# Can't Get Authenticate Swift ContextBuilder with Latest OpenStack

Tags: java, openstack-swift, jclouds

i have installed the latest OpenStack and I'm using Java and jclouds SDK to interact with OpenStack Swift, in the OpenStack environment that I'm using, the identity API version is `/identity/v3/` and the Swift API version is `v1/`, my code is:

```
blobContext = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(PROVIDER)
        .credentials(username, apiKey)
        .endpoint(EndPoint)
        .overrides(multipartProperties)
        //.buildApi(RegionScopedBlobStoreContext.class);
        .buildView(RegionScopedBlobStoreContext.class);
String blobRegion = blobContext.getConfiguredRegions().iterator().next();
```

**so at the line** `String blobRegion = blobContext.getConfiguredRegions().iterator().next();` i get the exception:

```
request: POST http://devstack.####.com:#####/v1/tokens HTTP/1.1  [Sensitive data in payload, use jclouds.wire.log.sensitive override to enable logging this data.] failed with response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

this code used to work in the past, yet in the past i wasn't using the latest OpenStack and the important thing is that my identity service is **Project-scoped** not **Domain-Scoped** (refer to [this link](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/pike/api_curl_examples.html#project-scoped)) 
and the swift API is: `http://devstack.####.com:#####/v1/`
and I'm using the latest jclouds API

and i believe this problem will appear in all ContextBuilders, so is there anyway that i can solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use jclouds against new OpenStack environments (running Keystone v3) you must use jclouds >= 2.1.0 and configure the ContextBuilder with the appropriate Keystone properties as detailed here:
https://jclouds.apache.org/blog/2018/01/16/keystone-v3/